# Why don't I get the CSS transition effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not getting the CSS transition effect for some reason and I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/0nhp4yzp/) that solved the problem and the overlay comes delayed sliding from top.

But on my [webpage](http://www.koolbusiness.com/customer_service.htm?msgid=msg_sent) it is not working and the overlay is immediate. Why? The code is the same that works on other pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-IN" class="js">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>
        </title>
    <!-- CSS INCLUDES: -->
    <!-- Le styles -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href="/static/css/common_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('[class^="item_arrow_"]').css('height', 'auto');
        //alert('test');
        $(function() {
            {% if message %}
        $('#message1').toggleClass('in');
            {%  endif %}

});
    </script>
</head>
<body name="body">
 <div id="message1" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable flyover flyover-centered">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <strong></strong> {{ message }}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `in` class is not by default assigned to the `message1` div ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. It seems that the toggle in the script is working but the transition is not having an effect. What did you mean?

Comment: when i see the code in the console, i find that the message1 div has the `class` **in**, so If you uncomment the `alert` line, the alert is displayed ? and if you comment the `toggleClass` line, the div steel displayed in load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know really why you have this problem (the code looks right), try this hack maybe that will solve the issue :

**JS :**

Instead of :

```
 $('#message1').toggleClass('in');
```

Add `setTimeout()` to the code to fire the toggle after 1 second of page ready , if that not work try 3000 (3s) :

```
 setTimeout(function(){
      $('#message1').toggleClass('in');
 }, 1000);
```

Hope that solve your problem.